# call Function of Adapter on a Button.setOnclickListner

Tags: java, android, method-call

**I want to call onChildRemoved method in CommentAdpter on commentDelete onclickListner as it is a inner class method so it is giving error everywhere where i tried to put setOnclickListner**  so please tell me how to setOnclickListner to this button so this method/function can call or do the delete work for comment

```
package com.ecbclass.database;

public class PostDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "PostDetailActivity";
    public static final String EXTRA_POST_KEY = "post_key";

    private DatabaseReference mPostReference;
    private DatabaseReference mCommentsReference;
    private ValueEventListener mPostListener;
    private String mPostKey;
    private CommentAdapter mAdapter;
    private TextView numStarsView;
    private TextView mAuthorView;
    private ImageView mAuthorPhotoView;
    private TextView mTitleView;
    private TextView mBodyView;
    private EditText mCommentField;
    private Button mCommentButton;
    private RecyclerView mCommentsRecycler;
    private TextView mStreamView;
    private TextView mSubjectView;
    private static ProgressDialog progress;
    private LinearLayoutManager mCommentManager;
    private Button commentDelete;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_detail);

        //progress bar for network chek
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.setMessage("Server not reachable.Check internet Connection");
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

        // Get post key from intent
        mPostKey = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_POST_KEY);
        if (mPostKey == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must pass EXTRA_POST_KEY");
        }

        // Initialize Database
        mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("posts").child(mPostKey);
        mCommentsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("post-comments").child(mPostKey);

        // Initialize Views
        mAuthorView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_author);
        mAuthorPhotoView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.post_author_photo);
        mTitleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_title);

        mBodyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_body);
        mBodyView.setScroller(new Scroller(this));
        mBodyView.setMaxLines(4);
        mBodyView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mBodyView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        numStarsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_num_stars_cmnt);
        mStreamView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_stream);
        mSubjectView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_subject);

        mCommentField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_comment_text);
        mCommentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_post_comment);
        mCommentsRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_comments);
        mCommentButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mCommentManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mCommentManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mCommentManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mCommentsRecycler.setLayoutManager(mCommentManager);

        commentDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.comment_delete);

        isOnlne();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        isOnlne();
        // Add value event listener to the post
        // [START post_value_event_listener]
        ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
                Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                setTitle(post.title);
                mAuthorView.setText(post.author);
                mTitleView.setText(post.title);
                mBodyView.setText(post.body);
                mStreamView.setText(post.stream);
                mSubjectView.setText(post.subject);
                if (post.userImage.equalsIgnoreCase("phone")) {
                    mAuthorPhotoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_call_icon);

                } else {
                    Picasso.with(PostDetailActivity.this).load(post.userImage)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.google)
                            .error(R.drawable.ic_action_account_circle_40)
                            .into(mAuthorPhotoView);
                }
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Getting Post failed, log a message
                Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                Toast.makeText(PostDetailActivity.this, "Failed to load post.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        };
        mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
        // [END post_value_event_listener]

        // Keep copy of post listener so we can remove it when app stops
        mPostListener = postListener;

        // Listen for comments
        mAdapter = new CommentAdapter(this, mCommentsReference);
        mCommentsRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // Remove post value event listener
        if (mPostListener != null) {
            mPostReference.removeEventListener(mPostListener);
        }

        // Clean up comments listener
        mAdapter.cleanupListener();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = v.getId();
        if (i == R.id.button_post_comment) {
            postComment();
        }
    }

    public String getUid() {

        String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        if (uid == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return uid;
    }

    private void postComment() {
        final String uid = getUid();
        final String userImage;
        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String str = currentUser.getEmail();
        if (str != null && str != "") {
            userImage = currentUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        } else {
            userImage = "phone";
        }
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        // Get user information
                        User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        String authorName = user.username;

                        // Create new comment object
                        String commentText = mCommentField.getText().toString();
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(commentText)) {
                            mCommentField.setError("comment shouldn't empty");
                            return;
                        }
                        isOnlne();
                        Comment comment = new Comment(uid, authorName, commentText, userImage);

                        // Push the comment, it will appear in the list
                        mCommentsReference.push().setValue(comment);
                        // Clear the field
                        mCommentField.setText(null);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }

    private static class CommentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView authorView;
        public TextView bodyView;
        public ImageView authorPhotoView;

        public CommentViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            authorPhotoView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_photo);
            authorView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_author);
            bodyView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_body);
        }
    }

    private class CommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentViewHolder> {

        private Context mContext;
        private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
        private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;

        private List<String> mCommentIds = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<Comment> mComments = new ArrayList<>();


        public CommentAdapter(final Context context, DatabaseReference ref) {
            mContext = context;
            mDatabaseReference = ref;

            // Create child event listener
            // [START child_event_listener_recycler]
            ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

                    // A new comment has been added, add it to the displayed list
                    Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    // Update RecyclerView
                    mCommentIds.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    mComments.add(comment);
                    notifyItemInserted(mComments.size() - 1);
                    mCommentManager.scrollToPosition(mComments.size() - 1);
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

                    // A comment has changed, use the key to determine if we are displaying this
                    // comment and if so displayed the changed comment.
                    Comment newComment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
                    String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    int commentIndex = mCommentIds.indexOf(commentKey);
                    if (commentIndex > -1) {
                        // Replace with the new data
                        mComments.set(commentIndex, newComment);

                        // Update the RecyclerView
                        notifyItemChanged(commentIndex);
                        mCommentManager.scrollToPosition(commentIndex);
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "onChildChanged:unknown_child:" + commentKey);
                    }
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }

                ******@Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChildRemoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    // A comment has changed, use the key to determine if we are displaying this
                    // comment and if so remove it.
                    String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    int commentIndex = mCommentIds.indexOf(commentKey);
                    if (commentIndex > -1) {
                        // Remove data from the list
                        mCommentIds.remove(commentIndex);
                        mComments.remove(commentIndex);

                        // Update the RecyclerView
                        notifyItemRemoved(commentIndex);
                        mCommentManager.scrollToPosition(commentIndex);
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "onChildRemoved:unknown_child:" + commentKey);
                    }
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }*******

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

                    // A comment has changed position, use the key to determine if we are
                    // displaying this comment and if so move it.
                    Comment movedComment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
                    String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                    // ...
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "postComments:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed to load comments.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
            ref.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
            // [END child_event_listener_recycler]

            // Store reference to listener so it can be removed on app stop
            mChildEventListener = childEventListener;
        }

        @Override
        public CommentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_comment, parent, false);
            return new CommentViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(CommentViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Comment comment = mComments.get(position);
            holder.authorView.setText(comment.author);
            holder.bodyView.setText(comment.text);
            if (comment.userImage.equalsIgnoreCase("phone")) {
                holder.authorPhotoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_call_icon);

            } else {
                Picasso.with(mContext).load(comment.userImage)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.google)
                        .error(R.drawable.ic_action_account_circle_40)
                        .into(holder.authorPhotoView);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            numStarsView.setText(String.valueOf(mComments.size()));
            return mComments.size();
        }

        public void cleanupListener() {
            if (mChildEventListener != null) {
                mDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
            }
        }

    }

    public void isOnlne() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            changeStatus(true);
        } else {
            changeStatus(false);
        }
    }

    // Method to change the text status
    public void changeStatus(boolean isConnected) {
        // Change status according to boolean value
        if (isConnected) {
            progress.dismiss();
        } else {
            progress.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        NetworkCheker.activityPaused();// On Pause notify the Application
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        NetworkCheker.activityResumed();// On Resume notify the Application
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
commentDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mAdapter.onChildRemoved(dataSnapshot);
    }
});
```

Comment: And **where should i put this code** in my file.Because anywhere i put it,it give error in **mAdpter** or **datasnapshot**

Comment: @UttamMeerwal you should put it in PostDetailActivity  in onCreate and you should pass the value of dataSnapshot to the function

Answer (score 0):

> First close the constructor brackets of your CommonConstructor.

```
commentDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v){
       mAdapter.onChildRemoved(yourdatasnapshot);


}
```

`